# how to use errorhandler middleware in express 4.x

Tags: node.js, express, middleware

I tried to use middleware errorhandler， but doesn't work, even i set `process.env.NODE_ENV ='development'`

below is the server code:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var errorhandler = require('errorhandler');
var notifier = require('node-notifier');
process.env.NODE_ENV = 'development'; //just purposely do this, see if it can work
if (process.env.NODE_ENV == 'developmet') {
    app.use(errorhandler({ log: errorNotification }));
}

function errorNotification(err, str, req) {
    var title = 'Error in' + req.method + '' + req.url;
    notifier.notify({
        title: title,
        message: str
    });
}
app.get('/', function (req, res, next) {
    nonexist(); //the error is still captured Native node.js not errorhandler
    res.send('this is home page!');
    next();
});
app.listen(1338);
```

no matter what kind of options i tried in errorhandler, it still doesn't work. 
can anyone help me to check any setting is wrong?

Comment: You need to explain what "doesn't work" means.  What behavior are you expecting?  What behavior do you see?  In general, error handling middleware should be installed last so it gets LAST crack at the request.  Also, what does `nonexist()` do?  And, why are you calling `next()` after doing `res.send()`.  That is wrong.  You only call `next()` when you want more route handlers or middleware to process the request.

Comment: Just try this var errorHandler=require('errorhandler'); if ('development' == app.get('env')) {
  app.use(errorHandler());
}

Comment: Change == operator as === in (process.env.NODE_ENV== 'development')

Comment: `next()` or no `next()` doesn't matter.  `nonexist()` just purposely make error out.  if it works, i should see notification pop out in my taskbar

Comment: i tried changed to '===',  and 'development' ==app.get('env). both doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Error handling is declared after all your other routes. Express moves through routes from top to bottom or left to right (if you imagine all your code on one line).

You can capitalize on this by putting a splat route after all your other routes, and it will be activated if no other exact route matches. This is how you can do an error 404 page.

It's why you build your routes like this (which will prepare you for React Router 'switch component', if you move into React coding):

```
GET /test/:slug
GET /test
GET /
```

Here is an example of a splat route and following that, your error handler middleware:

```
// Try switching the order of these first two
app.get('/', async (req, res, next) => {
    return res.status(200).send('test')
})
app.get('*', async (req, res, next) => {
    return res.status(404).send('error 404') // res.render('error/404')
})

// ERRORS
app.use(async (err, req, res, next) => {
    // if next() is called with a parameter, which can be anything,
    // this middleware will fire
    res.status(500).send('error 500') // res.render('error/500')
    throw err
})

// Try replacing your default route with this now
app.get('/', async (req, res, next) => {
    return next('Extreme detonations')
})
```

You do not need the async functions as I have shown here, but I do it as a matter of convention so I can always slap `await` in there. I use explicit returns to prevent any issues with sending headers after they are already sent, and because async functions return promises, so explicit return will resolve them.

All my routes generally look like this:

```
app.get('/admin', async (req, res, next) => {
    try {
        if (!req.user) throw 'garbageUser'
        const poop = await something()
        return res.render('template', {
            data: obj,
            bonusData
        })
    } catch (e) {
        if (e === 'garbageUser') {
            log.add(`illegal: ${req.originalUrl} from ${sniffer.getClientIp(req)}`)
            return res.render('403')
        }
        return next(e)
    }
})
```

This should hopefully be informative for you and offer some code to forensically analyze. The Express error handler middleware takes a 4th parameter in the first position called `err` which contains the value passed into `next()`.

Check out the Express documentation again after studying this, and it will make much more sense :)

> To answer your question:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
// You can add these back now that you understand
// var errorhandler = require('errorhandler');
// var notifier = require('node-notifier');

function handleErrors(error) {
    console.log('I'm telling your mom about this: ' + error);
}

app.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
    return next('REALLY BAD');
    return res.send('this is home page!');
});

// Remember, this must be after all your other routes
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
    console.log('Problem occurred, we could put logic here...');
    console.log('Error was: ' + err);
    if (err === 'REALLY BAD') {
        handleErrors(err);
    }
    next();
});

app.listen(1338);
```

Try commenting this out now `return next('REALLY BAD');` and run it again. You should see "this is home page!".

When you call `next()` with no parameter in it, Express treats it as no error. If you pass any value in, like `next(err)` or `next('Chicken tastes good')`, you will see `err` defined with that value in your error handling middleware.

Comment: thank you. but i just want basic middleware errorhandler can work based on official demo.  and your code confuse me more with `async (req, res, next)`. i am new in Node.js and Express.

Comment: Here, I will add an example for you at the bottom of the answer. The part confusing you is `function name() { return 'Sunny' }` is the same as `var name = () => { return 'Sunny' }`. It is newer syntax. Sorry, I didn't realize the exact state of learning you are at. You should also know that `const` and `let` are essentially the same as `var`, but they are more expressive. Const means constant, which means you cannot reassign it. Let means your intention is to possibly "mutate" the value of the variable.

Comment: Ok, take a look at it now. Everything after the yellow bar is new.

Comment: Try and remember this is called fat arrow syntax: `() => {}` is the same as `function() {}`. You will see it often. It is most often used when functions are passed into other functions, so this: `getSomething(args, function(data) { return data })` is the same as `getSomething(args, (data) => { return data })`

Comment: All fat arrow syntax does is remove the word `function` and put the `=>` on the right side.

Comment: It has other benefits also which will begin to clean your code up extremely once you are able to harness its power. Have fun!

Comment: If you want to research some of the concepts I showed you, look at: "async functions", "promises", "callback hell", "async/await", "template literals", "try/catch blocks", "explicit return" "implicit return", and "if statement shorthand". Sorry, I wasn't thinking that many small details could add up to very confusing.

Comment: thank you for your patient and detail explanation. actually i know about ES6 syntax although new in Node.js. your method is pretty good to learn how to use async function in router. learnt a lot... it is built in Express framework. actually my question is that the 3rd party middleware errorhandler doesn't work.  anyway this works fine and can also solve my problem. :)